# two dimensional array sum of columns

Tags: java, arrays

I have two dimensional array as below:

[33] [96] [34] [11] [65] [68] [12] [8 ] [=327]

[94] [91] [3 ] [20] [16] [59] [74] [97] [=454]

[29] [0 ] [31] [13] [4 ] [63] [52] [73] [=265]

[51] [3 ] [55] [74] [52] [79] [61] [74] [=449]

[18] [19] [1 ] [53] [33] [93] [26] [14] [=257]

[56] [41] [4 ] [16] [45] [8 ] [57] [22] [=249]

[43] [33] [43] [59] [61] [58] [58] [69] [=424]

[38] [41] [42] [29] [27] [72] [85] [75] [=409]

[36] [3 ] [23] [65] [40] [56] [41] [96] [=36]

[=?] [=?] [=?] [=?] [=?] [=?] [=?] [=?]

how to get the sum of the columns in the array?

here is my code to get the sum of the rows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] nums = new int[9][9];
    int random, total_rows=0, total_cols=0;
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();

    for (int i=0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < 9; j++) {
            random = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
            nums[i][j] = random;

            if(j < 8) {
                total_rows += random;
            }else {
                System.out.print("=");
                nums[i][j] = total_rows;
                total_rows = 0;
            }

            System.out.print(nums[i][j] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: How come the sum of the last row there is 36?

Comment: @Null It should be 360. He dropped the 0.

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
int[][] num = new int[9][9];
/*
 * ...populate the array
 *
 */
for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < num[i].length; j++) {
        sum += num[j][i];
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd separate your array-generation code from your summation/display code.
You should then be able to notice that all you'll have to do is flip `i` and `j` when accessing the array in the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

Homework question :)

So, instead of giving you code, I'm going to tell you that you are quite close to the answer already.

To tally the columns, you need a separate array, and then, as you create each column in each row, simply add that value to the correct position.

At the end of the day, you will have the row total, as well as the column total.  Given what you've done thus far, it should be easy for you to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code;

## Demo Code for Sum of Rows and Columns of a 2d-Array

```
import java.util.Random;

public class SumOfColumns {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] nums = new int[9][9];

        handleArray(nums);

        printArray(nums);
    }

    private static int getSumOfRow(int[][] array, int rowNum) {
        int sumOfRows = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < array[rowNum].length; i++)
            sumOfRows += array[rowNum][i];

        return sumOfRows;
    }

    private static int getColumnSum(int[][] array, int columnNum) {
        int sumOfColumn = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            sumOfColumn += array[i][columnNum];

        return sumOfColumn;
    }

    private static void handleArray(int[][] array) {
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();

        for (int i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                int random = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
                array[i][j] = random;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void printArray(int[][] array) {
        System.out.printf("       ");
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            System.out.printf("%4d ", i);
        System.out.println("\n   __________________________________________________");

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%4d | ", i);

            for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
                System.out.printf("%4d ", array[i][j]);

            System.out.printf("| Sum = %4d", getSumOfRow(array, i));

            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("   __________________________________________________");

        handleSumOfColumnPrint(array);
    }

    private static void handleSumOfColumnPrint(int[][] array) {
        System.out.printf("       ");

        for(int i = 0; i < array[0].length; i++)
            System.out.printf("%4d ", getColumnSum(array, i));
    }

}
```

## Sample Output

```
          0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8 
   __________________________________________________
   0 |    1   86   95   71   78   21   85   99   35 | Sum =  571
   1 |   45   82   68   75   30    1   71   94    8 | Sum =  474
   2 |   33   78   61   74   52   75   63    8    1 | Sum =  445
   3 |   17   10   99   78   61   73   63   40    8 | Sum =  449
   4 |   66   68   54   74   28   78   13    4   79 | Sum =  464
   5 |   75   60   79   76   55   14   20   28   27 | Sum =  434
   6 |   17   17   29   39    6   90    0   94   75 | Sum =  367
   7 |   57   89   73   27   28   42   92   36   16 | Sum =  460
   8 |   40   44   79   64   92   90   43   60   53 | Sum =  565
   __________________________________________________
        351  534  637  578  430  484  450  463  302
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Array[][] // Vertical, Horizontal. 

//sum of row n:
sum=0
for(int i:Array[n]){
    sum+=i;
}

//sum of column n:
sum=0
for(int i=0;i<Array.length();i++){
    sum+=Array[i][n];
}
```

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Homework question by any chance?

If so, maybe some hints would be more helpful?

You are calculating the row total while you are generating the 2d array - since you are doing this row by row it makes it easy for you to calculate this for rows (as you can build it up as you go along), but more tricky for columns since you effectively lose track of the previous rows each iteration.

If you *only* generate the array in the first for loops you will have a fully populated 2d array, but no row/column totals. But the data remains in your array, so you can now write code to calculate these totals.

As a small hint: if you wrote another loop after generating the data along the lines of:

```
int columnTotal = 0;

for (int r=0; r < 9; r++) {
    columnTotal += nums[r][0];
    }
```

that should let you sum the values of the first column (column 0).

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code to solve the problem...

```
import java.util.Random;

public class columnsAndRowsSummatory
    {
    static int x = 0;
    static int y = 0;

    public static void main (String[] arg)
    {
        String spaces = "       " ;
        //There are 7 spaces on the spaces String
        int[][] nums = new int[9][9];
        int random, rowTotal = 0, colTotal = 0;
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        String ColTotal = "";

    for ( x = 0; x < nums.length -1; x++) 
    {
        rowTotal = 0;
        for (y = 0; y < nums.length ; y++)
        {
            random = randomGenerator.nextInt(10000);
            nums[x][y] = random;
            while( y < nums.length -1 )
                {
                rowTotal = rowTotal + random;
                break;
                }

            if(y < nums.length -1 && x != nums.length -1 && random != 0)
            {
                int z = (int)Math.floor(Math.log10(random) );
                System.out.print(random + spaces.substring( (z) ) );
                //This method calculates how many digits does the number 'random'
                //Have and takes that amount away from the spaces string to even 
                //Out numbers displayed
            }
            else if(random == 0 && x != nums.length -1)
            {
                System.out.print(random + spaces);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.printf("=  %d ", rowTotal);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    for(x = 0; x < nums.length -1; x++)
    {
        for (y = 0; y < nums.length -1 ; y++)
        {
            colTotal = colTotal + nums[y][x];
        }
        int z = (int)Math.floor(Math.log10(colTotal) );
        ColTotal = ColTotal + colTotal + spaces.substring(z) ;
        colTotal = 0;
    }
    System.out.print(ColTotal + "<-Totals^");
}
}
```

Now in this code would display a neat array of how many number of rows and columns you want and it would display the column/row total on the corresponding last line of the array. If you would be dealing with numbers higher than 10 million, then all you need to do is add a space to the spaces string and you're good to go.

For example if you have

```
random = randomGenerator.nextInt(999999);
```

It would display something like this:

```
711778  119342  62648   8035    652270  344935  101175  265275  174969  =  2440427 
414592  798519  453329  988340  180647  540748  572587  675951  903581  =  5528294 
747535  955957  47966   742898  773810  34212   914212  625716  209569  =  5051875 
492510  998618  622957  517383  704277  397076  970357  280134  842993  =  5826305 
190916  57734   590635  944535  991653  366530  145640  402605  456611  =  4146859 
117598  612710  967466  67209   660383  247281  304953  141144  260186  =  3378930 
635384  660332  768930  340590  800611  758383  41154   289514  189504  =  4484402 
173484  740549  226505  921889  135020  555594  554520  65581   433272  =  3806414 
796617  601478  77503   161865  891582  715084  14614   189920  568788  =  4017451 
4280414 5545239 3817939 4692744 5790253 3959843 3619212 2935840 4039473 <-Totals^
```